# C++ beginner no match for 'operator-'

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, string-operations

I've ran into an issue with one of my intro to c++ labs. I have posted the instructions to this lab and my code below. I would like point out that Pattern B must be displayed beside pattern A(exactly as shown) and not below it.

[image: C++ Lab Assignment]

When I attempt to build this code I get the error no match for 'operator-' on the line b = b-y. Is there a simple method of decrementing the symbols within the string? The instructions state to use a second loop for pattern B but I'm not sure where to start with that.  I would really appreciate any advice that will steer me in the right direction to completing this assignment. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string a = "*";
    string b = "**********";
    string y = "*";


    for (int i=0; i <= 9; i++) {
        cout << a << "       " << b << "\n";
        a = a + y;
        b = b - y;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can concatenate a string using `+` but not remove a section using `-`

Comment: You can use the [`erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) function to _"decrement"_ the string.

Comment: Please don't try to guess C++ syntax. Read your book and documentation instead.

Comment: Read the assignment **carefully**. You are supposed to use a loop to display Pattern A, **and another loop** to display Pattern B.

Comment: Plenty of methods available: `.resize( )` would work as well. Or `.pop_back( )`. None of these are content-sensitive though, they'll remove anything.

Comment: @n.m.: I don't think that's actually possible. The exercise clearly states that the patterns have to appear side by side, and C++ has no way to move the cursor up again. If a first loop prints pattern A, the second loop prints pattern B _below_ pattern A which is specifically banned.

Comment: Why not keep a counter for the number of '+' symbols that need to be displayed in A and increment it, and a counter for B and decrement it? The excersize doesn't demand use of strings. You can move the cursor in the console, but the functions that do that are OS dependent

Comment: @MSalters I have no idea what's in the head of his instructor (probably not much) but I would interpret this as a requirement to print a single line of Pattern A using a loop, then a single line of Pattern B using another loop.

Comment: @Chase Gould  It looks like the task is impossible. At least I can't imagine now how to use two loops one after another to output the patterns side by side.

Comment: @n.m.: Fair idea, that's the closest you could get. Still a third loop for the lines, but at least it has _enough_ loops. Not what I'd use though. (`std::string` ctor taking char and count)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understood it:

```
#include <iostream>   
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int aCount = 1;
    int bCount = 10;
    while(bCount > 0) 
    {
        // Loop over A
        for (int i = 0; i < aCount; i++)
        {
            cout << '+';
        }

        // Output a few tabs to separate the samples
        cout << "\t\t\t\t";

        // Loop over B
        for (int i = 0; i < bCount; i++)
        {
            cout << '+';
        }

        // Go to next line
        cout << endl;

        aCount++;
        bCount--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. When I run this code the last 3 lines of pattern b are out of line. I can't seem to understand why that is.

Comment: It's because of the way tabs behave - just output `20-aCount` spaces or something instead to align the start of B.

Comment: I solved this by replacing the line cout << "\t\t\t\t";
with:
    if (aCount <= 7 )
        cout << "\t\t\t\t";

        if ( a Count > 7)
        cout << "\t\t\t";

Comment: Thanks @Useless that looks cleaner.

Comment: Yeah, go with what Useless said. I didn't actually test this code :) Also, in case my interpretation of the assignment is wrong, it is possible to print all lines of pattern A first, and then pattern B, but that requires using OS dependent console functions, which I doubt is what the instructor meant

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'subtract' strings in c++. There is no '-' operator for strings.

One approach is to use  string.substring() to get a 'shortened' version of your original string:

```
b=b.substr(0, b.size()-1); // copy all but last character of b to b
```

Comment: Since C++11, `string` also has `pop_back`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no operator `operator -` in the class `std::string`. You should use the method `erase` instead,

However if you will output strings for each row then there will not be two loops one after another.

It seems the assignment means something like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() 
{
    while ( true )
    {
        const char c1 = '+';
        const char c2 = ' ';

        std::cout << "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): ";

        unsigned int n;

        if ( not ( std::cin >> n ) or ( n == 0 ) ) break;

        std::cout << '\n';

        for ( unsigned int i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
        {
            for ( unsigned int j = 1; j <= i; j++ )
            {
                std::cout << c1;
            }

            std::cout << std::setw( 2 * n - i ) << std::setfill( c2 ) 
                      << std::right << c2;

            for ( unsigned int j = n - i + 1; j != 0; j-- )
            {
                std::cout << c1;
            }

            std::cout << '\n';
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 10

+                   ++++++++++
++                  +++++++++
+++                 ++++++++
++++                +++++++
+++++               ++++++
++++++              +++++
+++++++             ++++
++++++++            +++
+++++++++           ++
++++++++++          +

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 9

+                 +++++++++
++                ++++++++
+++               +++++++
++++              ++++++
+++++             +++++
++++++            ++++
+++++++           +++
++++++++          ++
+++++++++         +

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 8

+               ++++++++
++              +++++++
+++             ++++++
++++            +++++
+++++           ++++
++++++          +++
+++++++         ++
++++++++        +

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 7

+             +++++++
++            ++++++
+++           +++++
++++          ++++
+++++         +++
++++++        ++
+++++++       +

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 6

+           ++++++
++          +++++
+++         ++++
++++        +++
+++++       ++
++++++      +

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 5

+         +++++
++        ++++
+++       +++
++++      ++
+++++     +

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 4

+       ++++
++      +++
+++     ++
++++    +

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 3

+     +++
++    ++
+++   +

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 2

+   ++
++  +

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 1

+ +

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```